# CORS - Post request with custom headers from react app to oas3-tools based nodejs Rest API returns network error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I am new to both React and Nodejs and the concept of CORS so bare with me. The issue I am having is when sending a POST request from my React app with a 'version' header to my Nodejs Rest API. It is not responding correctly to the pre flight request to allow the 'version' header to be used in the request, and so I am getting a 'NetworkError' in response to my request.
I already ran into an issue with adding middleware to the app generated by oas3-tools so have a function to insert it correctly and without the 'version' header everything seems to be working as intended.
it seems that the express router is actually dealing with the request here:

```
  // for options requests, respond with a default if nothing else responds
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    done = wrap(done, function(old, err) {
      if (err || options.length === 0) return old(err);
      sendOptionsResponse(res, options, old);
    });
  }
```

and the Cors code doesnt appear to get hit

React Request:

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
      headers.append('Origin', 'http://' + globals.restApiUrl);
      headers.append('version', '1');

      const response = await fetch(
        'http://' + globals.restApiUrl + '/User?Username=username&Password=password',
        {
          mode: 'cors',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: headers,
        }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        navigate('/homepage');
      } else {
        const json = await response.json();
        throw json;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error:', error);
    }
  };
```

configuraion of Nodejs (initial attempt):

```
'use strict'; 
var insertMiddleware = require('./helpers/insertMiddleware.js');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var oas3Tools = require('oas3-tools');
var serverPort = 8080;
const cors = require('cors');

/* swaggerRouter configuration*/
var options = {
    routing: {
        controllers: path.join(__dirname, './controllers'),
    },

};

// Genarate the app
var expressAppConfig = oas3Tools.expressAppConfig(path.join(__dirname, 'api/openapi.yaml'), options);
var app = expressAppConfig.getApp();

// Add cors middleware 
insertMiddleware.insertMiddleware(app, cors({origin: '*', allowedHeaders: '*'}));

// Initialize the Swagger middleware
http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
    console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
    console.log('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
});
```

Second attempt:

```
'use strict';
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var oas3Tools = require('oas3-tools');
var serverPort = 8080;
const cors = require('cors');

/* swaggerRouter configuration*/
var options = {
    routing: {
        controllers: path.join(__dirname, './controllers'),
        preMiddleware: [cors({ origin: '*', allowedHeaders: '*' })],
        postMiddleware: [cors({ origin: '*', allowedHeaders: '*' })],
    },

};

// Genarate the app
var expressAppConfig = oas3Tools.expressAppConfig(path.join(__dirname, 'api/openapi.yaml'), options);
var app = expressAppConfig.getApp();

// Initialize the Swagger middleware
http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
    console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
    console.log('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
});
```

Comment: Per the Fetch standard, [`Origin` is a forbidden request header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header), which means that client code cannot set a header of that name; attempts to do so are silently ignored by browsers.

Comment: CORS is something you configure on the _server_ side, not on the _client_ side.

Comment: Yes from what I have read the Origin tag is not necessary because the browser itself will add that tag and the code examples show both server side and client side for completeness

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was the position of the cors in the router stack, the insertMiddleware fuction was inserting any new middlewares 3 indexes from the top of the stack, but the cors need inserting 17 indexes down on the app generated by oas3-tools :)

```
module.exports.insertMiddleware = function insertMiddleware(app, middleware, positionFromTheTopOfTheStack) {

    var newPositionFromTheTopOfTheStack = 2;
    if (positionFromTheTopOfTheStack !== undefined)
    {
        newPositionFromTheTopOfTheStack = positionFromTheTopOfTheStack;
    }
    // Get the length of the stack before we add the new middleware 
    const stacksOriginalLength = app._router.stack.length;
    // Add the new middleware to the top of the stack
    app.use(middleware);
    // Take what was the last X elements in the stack and move them back to the end of the array
    app._router.stack.push(...app._router.stack.splice(stacksOriginalLength - newPositionFromTheTopOfTheStack, newPositionFromTheTopOfTheStack));
}
```

calling this function like this:

```
insertMiddleware.insertMiddleware(app, cors({ origin: '*', allowedHeaders: '*' }), 16);
```

did the trick

Comment: Ah yes, the order in which you stack your middleware tends to matter when CORS is involved. Well done.

Comment: yes the reason I didnt think it was because of it position in the first place was because the "origin: '*'" setting was working, but the 'OPTIONS' request must need handling earlier in the router stack, I still have a lot to learn :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Because preflight requests (those `OPTIONS` requests you're seeing) do not carry credentials, a CORS middleware must occur in front of any authentication middleware.